# printing to a file in a windows forms application---Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, file-handling

So I'm coding a program in Visual Basic that gets the user to input book details (ISBN Number, Author ........) and then prints the details to a file. I have the following code which displays the form and all the input boxes however I'm clueless on where I need to place the code to print to a file.

The code to print to the file is as follows

```
FileOpen(1, "C:\test\testbook.txt", OpenMode.Append)
PrintLine(1, ISBN & " " & Author & " " & Title & " " & PageCount)
FileClose()
```

I tried placing it in the sub for the form but that didn't work. My question is where do I have to put this code in order for it to print to a file

Full code:

```
Public Class createBookform
    Public ISBN, Author, Title As String
    Public PageCount As Integer

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        FileOpen(1, "C:\test\testbook.txt", OpenMode.Append)
        PrintLine(1, ISBN & " " & Author & " " & Title & " " & PageCount)
        FileClose()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        ISBN = TextBox1.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox3_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox3.TextChanged
        Author = TextBox3.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox4_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox4.TextChanged
        Title = TextBox4.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
        PageCount = TextBox2.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub OKbUTTON_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OKbUTTON.Click
        MessageBox.Show("New book entered successfully", "Book confirmation")
        Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

[windows form that opens when code is executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPE3w.png)

Comment: Traditionally, "printing to file" is when you print out a document and set the tick "To file" to create a `prn` file for the spooler. What you are trying to do is "saving to file". Ask yourself when that should happen. You are currently trying to do it right before the form is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless if I'm missing something, do you just mean to do:

```
Public Class createBookform
    Public ISBN, Author, Title As String
    Public PageCount As Integer

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
         ISBN = TextBox1.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox3_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox3.TextChanged
        Author = TextBox3.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox4_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox4.TextChanged
        Title = TextBox4.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
        PageCount = TextBox2.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub OKbUTTON_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OKbUTTON.Click
        FileOpen(1, "C:\test\testbook.txt", OpenMode.Append)
        PrintLine(1, ISBN & " " & Author & " " & Title & " " & PageCount)
        FileClose()
        MessageBox.Show("New book entered successfully", "Book confirmation")
        Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

?

Typically, you wouldn't bother with the variables or the `TextChanged` events at all, and you would just use this:

```
Public Class createBookform    
    Private Sub OKbUTTON_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OKbUTTON.Click
        FileOpen(1, "C:\test\testbook.txt", OpenMode.Append)
        PrintLine(1, TextBox1.Text & " " & TextBox3.Text & " " & TextBox4.Text & " " & TextBox2.Text)
        FileClose()
        MessageBox.Show("New book entered successfully", "Book confirmation")
        Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

And to make it clearer, you would rename your text boxes something that makes sense (e.g., `txbISBN` for the ISBN text box).

Comment: And they don't need any `TextChanged` handlers either.

Comment: @GSerg true!  Made an addition to help the OP a little more.